# Nuget packages without nuget package manager?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget

What does a nuget package actually consist of, apart from the compiled libraries?

Is it possible to download these packages without using the package manager and use them elsewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What does a nuget package actually consist of, apart from the compiled libraries?

[Take a look here](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20Package). Basically it is a file with the `.nupkg` extension which is nothing more than a .zip file containing the structure explained in the previous link and some xml metadata.

> Is it possible to download these packages without using the package manager and use them elsewhere?

Sure, simply download the `.nupkg` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Darin! However, I am unable to find a link to download the .nupkg file on say, http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EntityFramework

Comment: @virtualmic, Here: http://packages.nuget.org/v1/Package/Download/EntityFramework/4.1.10331.0

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov how were you able to figure out the URL for the package?

Comment: For particular version of the package: http://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/PACKAGE_YOU_WANT/VERSION_YOU_WANT

Comment: The link works perfectly, just enter the right package name and version... eg:  http://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/entityframework/6.1.1

Answer (score 29):

You can download them from http://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/<PACKAGE_YOU_WANT>/ using your browser.

You can get the package name from: http://packages.nuget.org/Packages

Example:
jQuery UI (Combined Library) Package is at: http://packages.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.Combined
To download: http://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/jQuery.UI.Combined/

Answer (score 7):

Based on @Gth685's answer, I made a Google Chrome extension that adds download links to package pages on http://nuget.org

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nutake/ibhhbcaipjilldjkhhblhgdedjgoecap?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Just so everyone knows, you can just create an account on nuget.org. Once logged in a download link will appear on the left toolbar that will allow you to directly download any .nupkg file.

Answer (score 1):

Additional comment:
After downloading the *.zip (example jquery) change the ending from *.zip to *.nupkg and then you are able to install them with the Package Manager in VS.
Perhaps it's just me who had to think about it for a while. If not, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this should be a comment, but I don't have enough rep.

Based on the html generated by the Chrome extension mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14992048/1623379), we can improve [gth685f's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8744201/1623379) by noting that, to download packages that are not the latest, the URL is `packages.nuget.org/api/v2/package/<PACKAGE_YOU_WANT>/<VERSION_NUMBER>` (note the incremented API version number too).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that the V2 api is the same format as V1 to download a package using your browser.

http://packages.nuget.org/api/v2/package//

Answer (score 0):

Referencing NuGet may work some (most?) of the time, but you may also run into versioning issues. For example, try adding the  [Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) to a .NET 4 project and examine the resulting `csproj` file.

First, you'll notice that some of the BCL assemblies have been overriden:

1. System.IO.dll
2. System.Runtime.dll
3. System.Threading.Tasks

**And now all referencing projects have to use these overrides as well** (since you can't reference multiple versions of the same assembly). Among other things, it means you lose updates to those assemblies (unless the BCL NuGet package is updated as well).

You will also notice your csproj contains the following entry (it won't work if you remove it):

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.13\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.13\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" />
```

I am not knowledgable about MSBuild, but I'm guessing this could affect your build environment.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the command line tool nuget.exe to download the nupkg file, like this:

`nuget install packageId`

to get the latest version, or

`nuget install packageId -Version version`

to get the specific version.