# How does Visual Studio "Manage Nuget Packages" know when an update is available?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

"No Package updates are available" appears in the "Updates" panel of the  Visual Studio "Manage Nuget Packages" for my package, even though the version number has changed.

How does the package manager know if Updates are available?

I have my own package which is created through our build, the version number is updated on each major release.
e.g. Version: 1.0.1307.1102.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a caching issue with Visual Studio.

I succeeded by simply:

1. changing the version number again with nuget pack -Version
   1.0.1307.1202.
2. renamed the file to the same as the originally installed nuget package.
3. and copying the .nupkg file to the same source location on the share again.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a Nuget package to your application Visual Studio creates the "packages" folder at the root of your project. Inside this folder there is one folder for each installed package. If you need to can edit the "YourPackageName.nuspec" and manually change the version.

For allowing auto-updates you need to create a new source pointing to your local folder containing your package. You can find more details on how to add a source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-to-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally).
Then Visual Studio will check in your local folder for new updates.