# Cross-project references between two projects

Tags: visual-studio, reference, typescript

Is it possible to make a reference between two TypeScript projects? Assume we have the following project structure:

[image: Structure]

`Module1.ts` contains:

```
module TestModule {
    export interface Interface1 {
    }
}
```

`Module2.ts` contains:

```
module TestModule {
    export interface Interface2 extends Interface1 {
    }
}
```

`Test1` is referenced in `Test2`. I get an error `Could not find symbol 'Interface1'` in `Module2.ts`. It works within one project, but I don't know how to make it visible from the other project... Maybe it's not possible for now.

**[Edit 1.]**
When I try to use `TestModule.Interface1` pattern, I get the same error (said in different way). But the IntelliSense sees my `Interface1`:

[image: IntelliSense]

**[Edit 2.]**
I have noticed I can't use files from the other project. Even if I have a correct reference (`/// <reference ...`) added and linked all the files in my 1st project.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's lots of ways you can do this.

**Option 1 - Project References (TypeScript 3.0+)**

If you are using TypeScript 3.0 then look at using project references. Read more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/07/30/announcing-typescript-3-0/#project-references).

**Option 2 - Build script**

Use something like [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript), [grunt-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ts), or just a batch script to copy the files over into a folder in the main project.

Alternatively, [run a build event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ke5z92ks(v=vs.100).aspx) in Visual Studio that will copy the files over to the main project.

**Option 3 - npm package**

If you use npm, you could create a package for your other project. Then you can use your package in your main project. [Specifying a local dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387210/188246) is a good way to do this or by using something like [sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia), which is a private repository server. I've never used it, but it looks like it would work well.

**Option 4 - NuGet package**

You could look into [creating a nuget package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package) and then [installing it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10240029/188246).

**Option 5 - `--declaration --outDir` compiler option**

You can set the `--outDir` compiler option or the `outDir` property in [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) with the directory to your other project then also compile it with `--declaration` so that it generates the declaration files (`.d.ts`) too. For example: `--declaration --outDir ../Test1/External`.

**Original Answer (Using `--out`)**

You can do something similar in Visual Studio if you right click on your library project and click properties. In the `TypeScript Build` tab, check off the option to `Combine JavaScript output into file` and specify the location in your main project you want it to go (Ex. `$(SolutionDir)/TypedApp/External/TypedLibrary.js`). Then also check off `Generate declaration files` in order to generate a `.d.ts` file.

[image: Setting up project for automated builds]

Once this is done, build your library project and then include the `.js`, and `.d.ts` in your main project. Include the `.js` file in your html and reference the `.d.ts` in your typescript files.

[image: Include files in main project]

Each time you rebuild the library project, it will automatically update the main project with the changes.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help! Just an additional note... say you have a situation where you want to share a "typescript library" across multiple projects. To do this, you need to come up with your own build method that involves generating the `.js`, `.d.ts`, and `.js.map` files (like above), then copies these files to each project that needs it. You could use a Post-build event to do the copying after the files are generated (`Project > Properties > Build Events > Post-build event command line`).

Comment: Yeah, I found it when you gave me the 1st answer:)

Comment: @DavidSherret you could also use a NuGet package to push your packaged libraries around. I do it with my compiled assemblies. TypeScript should be no exception.

Comment: @ElanHasson yeah, i've been meaning to update this answer

Answer (score 11):

The solution suggested by @dhsto works but I have found an alternative using linked folders. I have [written about it in detail in this article](http://frankcode.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/cross-project-typescript-unit-testing-part-1/), here is how it can be implemented:

It can be achieved by creating a folder to hold your references, I like to name this “_referencesTS”, the folder will contain all of the links to files from Test1. This can be done individually but would become very cumbersome if it had to be done for each new TS file. Linking a folder however will link all of the files beneath it, this can be done by editing the csproj file.

To edit the file right click the Test2 project and click “`Unload Project`”, then right click the project and click “`Edit Test2.csproj`”. Navigate to the `<ItemGroup>` that contains the `<TypeScriptCompile>` tags and insert the code below:

```
<TypeScriptCompile Include="..\Test1\**\*.ts">
   <Link>_referencesTS\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)</Link>
</TypeScriptCompile>
```

Replace the relative path to the location of your TS files in Test1, this uses the wildcarding (*) to link all .ts files (dictated by the `*.ts`) within all sub folders (dictated by the `\**\`)..

The TS files within these folders will now appear linked within Test2, allowing for automatic typescript referencing.

Note: The only downside to this approach is that when a new file is added to Test1 within a linked folder, the user has to unload and load the project or close and open the solution for it to appear in Test2.

Comment: This solution looks excellent! I can see the linked files of my projectB in my projectA explorer tree but I cannot import this references to be used in a class defined in projectA. Any idea?

Comment: It seems to work to me either with .ts and .d.ts if those files are really there but not with the link solution you propose here.

Comment: This worked excellently. I simply included ..\Source\**\*.* since I wanted to create two identical static file projects for nuget. One with the source as content and one with all the static files embedded. Excellent!

Comment: In my case the referenced library is in a different namespace. Visual Studio can identify the reference but at compile it fails. I put the two library in the same namespace, it did not help.

Answer (score 7):

Frustrated with the state of affairs, I wrote a NuGet package that mostly solves this problem.  Using the NuGet package you can just add a reference from one project to another and it will do the work of copying files around in a way that is safe from accidentally editing the wrong file and still gives intellisense and debugging.

Details can be found in the Readme.md, or you can just install the NuGet package and run (I recommend at least reading the how to use section).

https://github.com/Zoltu/BuildTools.TypeScript.FromReferences

Comment: +1 This seems to work well. Thanks very much for creating it. I'd like it even more if you could select not to copy across the js.map and .ts files as in my use case I don't require those.

Comment: @soupy1976 I don't mind adding those things as options, but since I don't use VS to write TypeScript anymore (I use VSCode now) I probably won't make the change myself.  I encourage submitting a PR though!  This is where the copy occurs, you'll need to get some configuration passed through and then wrap these in an if block: https://github.com/Zoltu/BuildTools.TypeScript.FromReferences/blob/master/code/FromReferencesTask.cs#L62-L65

Comment: This works really well, unfortunately my Visual Studio comes complaining that I have duplicate declarations when I generate a d.ts file for my .ts files. And when I don't include the file on my source controls, tfsbuilds complains that your nuget can't find the required d.ts.

Urgh, I'm so confused!

Comment: @Thomas Feel free to file an Issue in the GitHub repo about this.  I don't actively maintain the project anymore (I don't write TypeScript in VS anymore) but I can take a glance and see if there is an easy fix for your problem (once I fully understand it).

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add to the answer of David Sherret that the lib files to the TypedApp project could be added as Link files instead of depending on post build events.  I'm having some issues with post build events in big solutions with a lot of projects, and the link files are now working ok for me.  (I cannot add a comment to the answer because I only have 35 reputation points).

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling with the `--out` parameter you can simply reference Module1.ts from Module2.ts using `/// <reference` To learn more about code organization patterns in TypeScript see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

What visual studio language services sees available (which is everything) is different from what you compile and actually have available at runtime.

Comment: I know I can use `/// <reference` but the problem is my project is huge and I'd have to reference bilions of files. New TS supports sharing classes within the same module. And it works fine within one project, but cannot make it cooperate when I have two/or more projects... :(

Answer (score 1):

If you need to share the code between multiple projects you can always create a symbolic link on each project where you need it.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Comment: How can you do that in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1):

basarat's answer is the closest to being the most reliable solution for cross-project TypeScript references.  However, when merging shared TypeScript code with a referencing project's TypeScript  (important, for example, if you need to target different ECMAScript versions), the Source Map file doesn't resolve to the shared project's directories, so debugging won't work (in fact, Visual Studio often crashes after adding breakpoints to the files referenced in another project).

Linked files of any kind (Visual Studio links and symbolic links) don't work with debugging in any system (Visual Studio, Chrome, WebStorm, etc.)--linked files essentially don't exist to the ASP.NET debugger, nor any other debugger; they exist only in Visual Studio.

Please see this question/answer indicating what has worked great for both solid code maintenance and debugging in Visual Studio, Chrome, and Firefox, while still retaining the ability to combine shared code with the referencing projects' code (important, for example, if you need to target different ECMAScript versions): [Visual Studio: How to debug TypeScript in a shared project using IIS Express and cross-project references (no linking or duplicating files)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27761608/2033465)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer disallows debugging in Visual Studio when a breakpoint is set in the *Shared* project.  (At best the debugger will stop on a line in the compiled javascript, but not the original Typescript and certainly not in its original project location.)

In the Shared project's properties, let's say that *Combine Javascript output into [a single] file* is checked and set to `AllShared.js`, which also makes a `AllShared.d.ts` file because *Generate declaration files* is checked, and also makes a `AllShared.js.map` because *Generate source maps* is checked.

The referencing project should NOT copy or link these files in the way the accepted solution does. Instead:

Part 1, in the referencing project, create `/typings/tsd.d.ts` if it doesn't already exist, and append to the bottom of that file the line `///<reference path="../../SharedProject/AllShared.d.ts" />`.   Once this is done, (and at least one successful compile of SharedProject is done), Intellisense and the Typescript compiler should see Interface1 etc. (You'll likely get a red squiggly line underlining the statement if the path/file doesn't exist, which is nice.)

Part 2, in the referencing project's `index.html`, add the line `<script src="http://localhost:29944/AllShared.js"></script>` before that project's own script tags.  The localhost part comes from the Shared project's Properties, Web tab, Project Url. (Both 'IIS Express' and 'Local IIS' work.)

Now when you run the referencing project, you should see Internet Explorer** request the relevant files from their respective "websites". Visual Studio breakpoints should be hit regardless whether they're in SharedProject or the referencing project.

---

. Although this solution works without gulp/grunt/powershell, Visual Studio's *Combine Javascript output into one file* doesn't glue together the files in any particular order, and it will eventually break your code.  Then you'll need to add Gulp/etc. to the referencing project to insert a `<script src="http://localhost:29944...` tag for each file in Shared***, because keeping `index.html` updated by hand is a poor option.  (Adding Gulp to the Shared project, to concat the .js and .d.ts files into singles runs into an issue with .js.map files, which can't be simply concatted.)

** IE and VS are both Microsoft products, so IE really works better if you want to use VS's breakpoints and debugger instead of a web browser's.

*** Gulp doesn't like injecting urls, only filepaths.  Given HTML comments in `index.html` like `<!-- SharedStuff:js --><!-- endinject -->`, circumvent this like so:

```
gulp.task('insert-into-html', [], function () {
    var common = gulp.src(['../SharedProject/**/*.js'], { read: false });
    return gulp.src('./index.html')
            .pipe(inject(common, {
                relative: true,
                name: "SharedStuff",
                transform: function (filepath) {
                    return '<script src="http://localhost:29944/'+filepath+'"></script>';
                }
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: None of recommended solutions works and none of them can't be used in my case :(