# How can I use parent paths with a typescript project with IIS express?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, iis-express

So I have this:

**/projectA/index.html**

And for the sake only for testing I want to have this in index.html

```
<script src="../projectB/somefile.foo"></script>
```

Of course, when I run visual studio,  my foo file cannot be found because it is above the project "root".

Is there any way to allow IIS to gain access to projectB?

I am using TypeScript with Visual Studio 2013.

Note: I did google this, but I find `asp` stuff.  As far as I am aware, this is not relevant to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is trying to access the file at `../projectB/somefile.foo` relative to where the current page is. Ask yourself this question, if you were using a web browser, how would you navigate to `../projectB/somefile.foo`?

I'm going to make a bit of an assumption and guess that `index.html` is at a url that looks something like this:

```
http://localhost:55685/index.html
```

Now, as you pointed out, it doesn't really make sense to go up a directory using `../` when you are already in the root directory.

You have two options I can think of right now. One is that in the project's properties, on the Web tab you can configure a Project Url for `projectB`. For example `http://localhost:55685/projectB`. Then in your app do this:

```
<script src="http://localhost:55685/projectB/somefile.foo"></script>
```

You'll have to do some additional configuration if you ever deploy your application, but it's a solution that works if you just need it for development.

Another option is to copy the script files from `projectB` into `projectA`. **I would recommend this, especially if projectB isn't going to be deployed somewhere.** If you are trying to access some TypeScript files, you can use a method similar to what is outlined in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21311079/188246). Otherwise, just make a build event that runs a script to copy all your script files into `projectA`. After that, reference the script files you need at the location you copied them to in `projectA`.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to explain, I will check this out first thing tomorrow morning :)