# TypeScript code reference to other VS-Project: What is missing?

Tags: typescript

I have two independend Visual Studio projects both containing TypeScript code. Now I want to re-use some code from one project in the other. I have read about the possiblities and I think in my case I should use option 1 from here: [Stackoverflow: cross project references between two projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233108/cross-project-references-between-two-projects).

However I followed the required steps, but I still have the issue, that the referenced code is not recognized neither by code editor nor by compiler. The reported error is "TS2552: Cannot find name 'TypeA'".

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

FileA:

[image]

FileC:

[image]

tsConfig from ProjA:

[image]

tsConfig from ProjC:

[image]

So, obviously I miss something, but I cannot see what it is. Can you please advice so I can compile ProjC?

Hint: I used 'module' instead of 'namespace' because the real target project files are written with modules and are not subject to change.