# StorageClient does not exist in the namespace using Microsoft.WindowsAzure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

This code was working previously but on updating nuget packages something seems to have gone awry. If I add in the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient dll that had previously been deployed then it is not recognising the Cloud classes such as CloudBlobClient which I am using WindowsAzure.Storage nuget 4.2

I need this to be able to write to azure file services so cannot simply uncomment

Comment: Can you describe the exact problem you're facing? You mentioned that you want to write to Azure File Service but at the same time you mentioned about `CloudBlobClient`. For writing to File Service, you would use something like `CloudFileClient`

Comment: Yes I am using CloudFileClient I just named first class I saw on the page, I am trying a using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient but it tells me that storageclient does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.WindowsAzure which had been previously been working before nugets got changed for upgrade to MVC5

Comment: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient` is the old (and I mean really-really old) version. You should be using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`. What was the version of the storage client library before you updated to 4.2?

Comment: Why wouldnt this be picked up?

Comment: Then it tells me that storage is not part of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage namespace, I have the 4.1.0 dll in the project I am attempting to build

Comment: Get rid of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll` library from your project. I believe presence of both old and new (`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll`) is creating problem for you.

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll is in the project but when typing the using statement I do no see storage in intellisense

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient is shipped with the 2.4 tools for visual studio so not sure what is going on here to be honest but I cannot get my storage classes to be recognised since adding it despite the reference for either or even both being in the solution

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient namespace does not exist in the new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll. I would strongly recommend removing all references to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll and changing the code to use the new library.

If you still cannot see Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage after these steps, you can try uninstalling the NuGet package and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

Although the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient` DLL is likely [outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25191149/711006), I succeeded to download it manually from https://nuget.org/packages/AzureSDK2.2DLLs/ and install it to Visual Studio 2013 Community (using the [instructions from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10240180/711006)).