# How to create and use ASP.NET vNext class library NuGet package?

Tags: nuget-package, asp.net-core, dnx

I would like to create a NuGet package of my ASP.NET vNext class library. How can I do it, step by step? I understand there is `kpm build`, but I couldn't find a guide regarding where to download kpm, etc.

Also, after getting a NuGet package (or DLL) of it, how can I add it from local machine to my vNext project?

Answer (score 5):

Kpm is the package manager for the new KRuntime. Instructions on how to install the KRuntime command line utilities on your developer machine can be found on [the aspnet Home repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Home#getting-started). Once you have kvm and a version of the KRuntime set up you will have kpm available as well.

Now you can run `kpm build` on your class libraries project location. Output should be something like this:

```
kpm build src\ClassLibrary1\
ClassLibrary1 -> C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication1\src\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.1.0.0.nupkg
ClassLibrary1 -> C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication1\src\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.1.0.0.symbols.nupkg

Build succeeded.
    0 Warnings(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:01.7556414
```

The easiest way to add a reference to a class project is to do it in your project.json, assuming you have it in the same solution. Here is an example project.json from a web application, which references a class library called ClassLibrary1.

```
{
    "webroot" : "wwwroot",
    "exclude": "wwwroot/**/*.*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-alpha4",
        "ClassLibrary1": ""
    },
    "frameworks" : {
        "aspnet50" : { },
        "aspnetcore50" : { }
    }
}
```

If you want to set up a NuGet feed you can read [the official NuGet documentation to see how that is done.](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) Copy the outputs of `kpm build` into your NuGet feed.

Note: VS14 CTP4 only works with alpha4 of the KRuntime. If you want to use VS14 for vNext without errors popping up you need to downgrade your KRuntime to version 1.0.0-alpha4.

Comment: I've retracted my answer but leaving as comment in case anybody else comes here trying to figure this out for regular class libraries:

I used [Nuget Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com) to create the nuget packgage for the third party dll's that I needed to reference.

After simple drag & drop of dll in lib folder and filling out basic metadata in explorer, I created the package and added the path to Nuget Package Manager (CTP4 version) lookup directories. After that I added the nuget package name directly in project.json and it picked up like it picks up any other online packages.

Comment: I've tried this, but it breaks. My class library has a dependency on `"mongocsharpdriver": "1.9.2"`, it's in the `project.json` and it builds fine in VS. However it can't find this dependency when I try to build with `kpm`. It doesn't complain for Microsoft dependencies though. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say. The package location was moved between alpha3 and alpha4 so it might be that. Make sure your runtime is alpha4 at least. I tried using that package in a simple vnext project and it builds just fine.

Comment: My default runtime is `1.0.0-alpha4 CLR x86`

Answer (score 5):

#### Creating NuGet package from class library

If you use **Visual Studio 2015 RC** and later: go to your class library project properties, open `Build` tab and check `Produce outputs on build` option:

[image]

NuGet package will be created in `{SolutionDir}\artifacts\bin\{ProjectName}\{Configuration}` directory on each project build.

If you use **command line**:

1. Make sure you installed `DNVM` and `DNX` (see [ASP.NET Home repo](https://github.com/aspnet/home) for instructions).
2. Run `dnu pack` in the project directory. NuGet package will be created in `{ProjectDir}\bin\{Configuration}` directory by default.

#### Using packaged class library

To use the class library in another project from the same solution, add it as a usual project reference in Visual Studio or to `dependencies` property in `project.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "ClassLibrary1": ""
}
```

To use the library in other solutions, publish NuGet package to [nuget.org](http://www.nuget.org/) or any other NuGet feed and add it to your project using Visual Studio (`References` ~> `Manage NuGet Packages...`) or to `dependencies` property in `project.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment.

To update to whyleee's answer, according to the [migration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/migrating-from-dnx) posted on 8/8/16, the tools that were part of the DNX toolset have been superseded by the dotnet CLI tool.

So, `dnu pack` becomes `dotnet pack` and creates the nuget and symbols package in the bin/[Configuration] directory by default. You pretty much replace `dnu` with `dotnet` for most of the commands.

To add a nuget package locally, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-to-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally).

Answer (score 0):

As of VS2019, will need to update project properties / Package tab, and choose to "Generate NuGet package on build".

[Property Tab Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3EHq.jpg)