# How to Automate NuGet publishing for vNext Class Library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I created a new vNext Class Library in VS2015 RC for which NuGet package generation is activated ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30923940/837623)). I would like to automate the pushing of the generated package to a custom feed on successful build.

Currently I am manually executing the following command:

> nuget push {package file} -s http://{nugerservername}.azurewebsites.net/ {apikey}

Previously I used the Post-Build events to execute this line (along with the package generation script), but there is no such possibility for the new Class Library project template (I guess that is because of the new Dynamic Compilation).

Comment: you can add a postbuild command in your script section on project.json