# How to add a nuspec as a reference to a project

Tags: asp.net, nuget, nuget-spec

I am trying to add to my project a nuspec as reference.. by :
right click on references > add reference > browse > nuspec_file
it doesn't work... what is the right way to do it ?

Comment: I dowloaded a sample from pluralsight website, and to run the project I need to load a library (also from the website) the library saved inside a nuspec file, I need to use it in my project, never used nuspec before... so I want to know how to add it to my references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a NuSpec file directly.

- [Download the package explorer](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/using-a-gui-to-build-packages).
- Create a package from your NuSpec file
- Click File -> Save and store the `.nupkg` in a directory.
- [Add that directory as a package source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-to-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally).
- Right-click your project and click 'Manage NuGet Packages...'
- Select the directory package source and browse for your package.
- Find your package and click the Install button.

Comment: I downloded the package explorer, and open my NuSpec file, I  can see that my dll is inside, but I cant find the .nupkg.. I need to get that library (from nuspec ) and add it to my references in my project. how can I get my library ?

Comment: May be I am missing here something, when I do file -> Export f - I get 'No items match your search' ...

Comment: Ok I did the file-Export and it export to a new file I choose nugetPack.cmd, still can't touch my library.;.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!  only after saving the file as .nupkg - it is possible to add it to project using Nuget manager.