# Installing a NUGET package using NUSPEC file

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to install latest entity framework using nuget. Some how our company proxy wont allow to connect to nuget.
Hence we downloaded the package from

> packages.nuget.org/v1/Package/Download/EntityFramework/

The downloaded file is a zip file that contains stuff and one NUSPEC file.
My understanding was that I needed an NUPKG file to install a package but I am not sure how do I install this package.

Have I downloaded the correct file ? or how do I install this package then ?

Comment: _"The downloaded file is a zip file that contains stuff and one NUSPEC file"_ - that _is_ the nupkg file.

Comment: That URL *does* download a NuGet package. What are you asking?

Comment: Just put the nupkg file in a local folder and add it in the nuget settings

Comment: code caster -- that's a zip file downloaded.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. That link you posted lets you download a .nupkg file. This is a file in PK zip format, yes, but that's what a .nupkg is. See [How to install a Nuget Package .nupkg file locally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-to-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally).

Comment: @Muds, a Nuget package is a zip file with specific contents and an extension of `.nuget`. Hitting that URL downolads a 4MB `.nuget` file that contains Entity Framework. Did your file have a different extension? If so, your firewall toyed with it

Comment: @Muds - take a `NUPKG` file, rename the extension `ZIP` and you'll see a standard zip file. Take a `ZIP` file with the right layout (say, a `NUSPEC` at the root and other files) and rename it `NUPKG` and you've created a package.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I guess you are right, filewall must have player foul... let me rename and test again

Comment: @Muds I suggest you have a talk with your network folks. NuGet is a release channel for updates, fixes to .NET itself. By blocking it, they are forcing you to either use old and unfixed versions, or manually update packages when you realize that there *are* updates available.

Comment: i did that in first place mate, but guess they cant fix it somehow.. dunno whats wrong there really

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - i don't think this is duplicate to what you linked, its actually about wrong extension, i changed it to nupkg and it works now.

Comment: @Muds in that case it would be out of scope as an issue that can't be reproduced, or a networking issue

Comment: yea cant deny that, but your answer helped me.. hence it can be useful for someone else, but if its against rules, I would vote for closing!

Answer (score 6):

If you have the nupkg locally, you can simply create a folder on the local file system *anywhere*, and add that as a custom source - just drop the nupkg into that folder; I do this all the time for presentations, etc:

[image]

Comment: marc I don't have nupkg file .. my question is how to get that from the downloaded zip file

Comment: @Muds a nuget file is a zip file with a `.nuget` extension. If you got something else, you have to explain what you did and what is the extension of the file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if all you have is the nuspec, **nothing** will work; that isn't a useful file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos do you mean nupkg?

Comment: @MarcGravell the OP's firewall changed the package's extension to `.zip`. It was the only thing that made sense - a zip file that contains a nuspec file at the root