# How to install Odata in visual studio with no internet

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, odata

How can I install Odata on visual studio 2013 at a machine that is not connected to internet?

When I try to install it using the conventional way (by running this command: Install-package Microsoft.AdpNet.Odata) it gives me the following error:

Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: I guess, you have downloaded the package or have a backup. Just go to general settings in the nuget and install from there easily. Without backup, you can't do anything or commands will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the .nupkg file from Nuget.org on a machine that does have internet, copy it to the machine that doesn't have internet, and then use `Install-Package C:\Path\To\Some\File.nupkg`

Or for more options, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-to-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your command but it showed the same error. I tried the command in the question you shared but it showed thus error: enable to read package from path ... And i tried the other answer the nuget screen kept on trying to load for several minutes