# I can't add reference in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, dll, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm having issues right now on adding reference in Visual Studio 2017. So basically, I clicked on my project to show the collapsed menu where you can see folders, properties, and **references**. I right clicked **References** and chose **Add reference**. An error shows up and it says "The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported".

I'm currently using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.2.

Comment: What sort of project do you have? If it is a dotnet core project, make sure you have the latest version of the framework installed (https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd).

Comment: Yes. It is .Net core project. I tried to reinstall VS2017 earlier. I used the installer found on the link you provided but I'm still encountering the same issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how to diagnose that issue. Try creating a brand new dotnet core project using one of the templates that is installed along with the dotnet core workload. If you still cannot add a reference, your installation is likely corrupt (vague but not much to go on here). If you can add a reference to the new project, your existing one is likely misconfigured (perhaps due to an automatic upgrade from `project.json -> App.csproj`)

Comment: Is this an existing .net core 1.1 app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This thread helps me resolve the issue:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/28126/unable-to-add-reference-in-visual-studio-2017-refe.html

Just to sum it up, the thread says that I need to add a certain .dll file on the cache for me to add References. Not sure why this issue occur but I hope it helps anyone who encounters the same issue.

Comment: The defined thread help me solve the problem - Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Launch Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 under Visual studio Tools and go to path where the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll is located. OR 
Download from: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwOA9PgOV_oxSzV4V2ZvVnNmdDQ  Next, in the console point your path to the DDL's location

cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies 

Then Run this command: gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll

Comment: Works for VS 2019 as well, in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer didn't work for me. And despite me getting the same error message as the OP (and the person on the Microsoft forum), I was not getting any information in Visual Studio's ActivityLog.xml file.

I ended up having to pack my .dll in a NuGet package and add it to the project in that way. These links were helpful:

https://www.jweiler.com/create-nuget-packages-with-vs-2017/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48549013/253938

Answer (score 0):

But remember, you have to add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll not 12 or less than 11 for Visual Studio 2017 because it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I was selecting from the list of recent references, but not using the checkbox to the left of them. I'm an idiot.  Or am I?  Personally, I don't like how this selection works.  Why are the unchecked checkboxes hidden until I select an item?  Who does this?  And besides, I can select like a normal listbox but also check.  Very weird to me.