# VS2017 WinForms can't update service reference

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, visual-studio-2017

When I right click on the service reference and choose 'Update Service Reference' I get an error:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUNa9.png) The error seems so vague, I've tried reinstalling, modifying, ensuring all nugets match but no success.

This worked fine in vs 2015.

Comment: did  you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007007/i-cant-add-reference-in-visual-studio-2017?

Comment: Yes I did, everything installed successfully but it made no difference, got the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't add reference in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007007/i-cant-add-reference-in-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 0):

If the service reference you originally added was working but only updated incorrectly, you can try to delete the original service reference and add it again, if that still doesn't work, you can try this solution:

1. Open Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 as an administrator
2. Find the directory: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
3. Then inpute gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll

When the installation is complete, remember to restart  Visual Studio.