# visual studio toolbox bootstrap snippets

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

Under what conditions will the bootstrap snippets tab in the toolbox appear?

When a webform is added to a project, There is a design view for adding elements to the page.  Is there a view with a similar functionality for bootstrap elements?

No matter the combinations I have tried, I cannot get such a toolbox tab to appear, Is there something I haven't installed?  I have uninstalled and reinstalled from nuget many times in many combinations.

Is there a tutorial or web video that can provide from guidance?  I have tried every search combination I can think of and watched hours of videos and am coming up dry.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Bootstrap does not use a 'Drag and Drop' functionality nor there is a 'tab snippet', at least not on visual studio, unlike other.Net controls. Instead, the Bootstrap components are called either through [It's Library Files (Downloaded)](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/) or simply reference the files on the provided servers using [Bootstrap CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

Short answer: It uses CSS HTML and a little bit of JS.
I strongly recommend you look into [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) 
 and [Bootstrap Components](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/).

Also if you do not know how to include Bootstrap into Visual Studio manually: [CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064657/manually-install-bootstrap-in-visual-studio/47064753#47064753)

Comment: I was doing that silly assumption thing, that there might be extended functionality for the bootstrap elements.  As I think about it... it's just an html button with more stuff.

Comment: That's right and I'm glad you were able to figure it out, it's simply a normal HTML button with bits additional lines of code just to make it look cooler.