# VS2017 - Adding Bootstrap doesnt install files

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, .net-core

I have also just installed Bootstrap via Nuget package manager, and although Bootstrap seems to be within the Dependencies area, no additional files have been added to my project. See attached screenshot. Using Visual Studio 2017 Pro

[image]

problem seems to be related to :

[Manually Install Bootstrap in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064657/manually-install-bootstrap-in-visual-studio/49380318?noredirect=1#comment85762405_49380318)

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: There should be logs in the Package Manager Output window, you may be able to figure out the issues by reading the logs.

Comment: The logs have disappeared as I tried to reboot VS. I didnt get any errors when installing though. Perhaps I should uninstall and then reinstall, then check logs?

Comment: try to use `dotnet add package bootstrap --version 4.0.0` and then use `dotnet restore`.

Comment: Hi, I uninstalled my current Bootstrap then tried what you suggested. It seems as though package manager installed the files- Restore completed in 651.82 ms for C:\Users\<name>\Documents\Coding Stuff\BethanysPieShopV2\BethanysPieShopV2\BethanysPieShopV2.csproj.
Successfully installed 'bootstrap 4.0.0' to BethanysPieShopV2
Successfully installed 'jQuery 3.0.0' to BethanysPieShopV2
Successfully installed 'popper.js 1.12.9' to BethanysPieShopV2                                     however no files are added to WWWROOT

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `npm` configurating file

and inside this file write this code:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.1.1"
  }
}
```

To use bootstrap write this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```