# How to install .nupkg programatically from locally?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have created one nuget package with extension .nupkg. so i would like to install it using Nuget API where i can provide the locally availalbe .nupkg file programtically?

How to install .nupkg(available in specified location in system) programatically from console application?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a NuGet package .nupkg file locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-do-i-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally)