# Getting error while restoring NuGet packages Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've just downloaded the project code from VSTS.
While trying to build, it told me that some assemblies are missing and I couldn't download them from NuGet. 
It always gives me this error:

> Error Failed to download package
>   'Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime.1.0.3.1' from
>   'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.arch.lifecycle.runtime/1.0.3.1/xamarin.android.arch.lifecycle.runtime.1.0.3.1.nupkg'.
>   The HTTP request to 'GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.arch.lifecycle.runtime/1.0.3.1/xamarin.android.arch.lifecycle.runtime.1.0.3.1.nupkg'
>   has timed out after 100000ms.

I have this error for most of the linked assemblies.

I've tried to clean solution, remove NuGet cache, removed Nuget.config, but no luck.
I'm stuck there and anytime I've tried to upgrade or downgrade any of assemblies, it starts to download missing packages and get the same errors again.

Comment: did you try to download them manually?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-do-i-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally

Comment: yes I tried this, but the same problem appears, when doing this the IDE start to download missing assemblies and get the same errors again

Comment: try disabling package restore

Comment: I solved the problem by adding new assembly from nuget package manager console for each of projects, the application installed all the packages then the problem solved.