# Doing a local NuGet package installation but getting the error - Unable to get repository signature information

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I'm trying to do an offline NuGet package installation by following the answer by Samuel Jack here:
[Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-do-i-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally)

> *1. Add the files to a folder called LocalPackages next to solution*
>
> *2. Create a file called NuGet.config next to solution file*

The .nupkg files are stored locally and installed using NuGet Package Manager but  I'm getting this error - "Unable to get repository signature information for source https://api.nuget.org/v3-index/repository-signatures/5.0.0/index.json. Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)."

I don't understand why the package manager needs to get repository signature information from the internet when I'm trying to do an offline installation. Internet connection is blocked in my server & that's why I'm getting 403 error.

How do I install the NuGet packages locally without getting the error?

Comment: Please  disable package source on `Nuget.config` file like this: `<disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="xxxxx"(the source name of  `https://api.nuget.org/v3-index/repository-signatures/5.0.0/index.json`) value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>`. After that, [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete `C:\Users\xxxx\.nuget\packages`. After that, close VS Instance and restart your solution so that the new  `Nuget.config` file can works.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. You have solved my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I install the NuGet packages locally without getting the error?

You can try the following steps:

**Solution**

**1)** please make sure that you have these xml nodes in the new `Nuget.config` file:

```
<disabledPackageSources> 

<add key="xxxxx"(the source name of api.nuget.org/v3-index/repository-signatures/5.0.0/index.json) value="true" /> 

</disabledPackageSources>
```

**2)** [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete the **packages** folder under `C:\Users\xxxx\.nuget\packages`.

**3)** If you add the new `Nuget.config` file in your solution , it cannot work immediately, it needs a restart. You should restart VS and then open your project, and after that, it can work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case disabling package sources that were causing problems helped. (See the first comment from Mr Qian on the question) Global nuget config can be found at `%AppData%\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`