# Unable to add Controllers and Views in ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I created a solution on Visual Studio 2019 and that solution contains ASP.NET core MVC Web application. When i try to add new controllers it gives error and not able to add it.Error is "There was an error running the selected code generator. Unable to get repository signature information for source [https://api.nuget.org/v3-index/repository-signatures/5.0.0/index.json"](https://api.nuget.org/v3-index/repository-signatures/5.0.0/index.json%22)

Then I changed the package source of nuget package manager to my organizations's customized source on visual studio 2019.

After changing the source of nuget package manager, I tried again to add controllers and views but got different errors and not able to add it. Error is "There was an error running the selected code generator.Package restore failed.Rolling back package changes for projectname".

I tried cleaning nuget package cache but it didn't help me.

Please help me to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You try by clearing `ComponentModelCache`

First close all instaces of visual studio. Delete all the files from this folder C:\Users\ (your_user_name) \AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0\ComponentModelCache.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Got same error "There was an error running the selected code generator.Package restore failed.Rolling back package changes for projectname"

Comment: is it happening with any project and framwork (like .net 4.7 or .net core 2.0)? or any specific project?

Comment: it is happening  for all MVC projects which i create using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: If you try this way, `Right click on the target folder.` and the `From the list, choose Add => New Item.`,

Comment: Does any of this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61380157/90475