# Unable to install ApplicationInsights from Nuget for Azure Function app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on an Azure Function in .NET Core 6 but I'm unable to initialize `Application Insights`. I tried to install `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore -Version 2.20.0' but I'm unable to do so and get an exception:

[image]

Error:

[image]

I tried this command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore -Version 2.20.0
```

Comment: are you using `dotnet` or `donet-isolated` mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the below steps would help to fix the issue:

1. In Visual Studio - Azure Functions Project Publish Window > Click on `Restore Service dependencies and their settings` icon and then Install the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`.

[image]

2. Check [these options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting#quick-solution-for-visual-studio-users) are checked in VS > Tools > NuGet Packet Manager.

Also, please check this workaround given in this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61384638).

Answer (score 1):

Application Insights is added by Azure Functions automatically. You should not add the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` package to an Azure Functions project as there might be incompatibility issues doing it that way. Instead, if you want to write custom telemetry use the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights` NuGet packages located [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights) as shown by [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#install-the-application-insights-extension) and [those docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#log-custom-telemetry-in-c-functions):

> There is a Functions-specific version of the Application Insights SDK that you can use to send custom telemetry data from your functions to Application Insights: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights