# AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry not recognise in Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, .net-6.0, telemetry

I am working on .NET CORE 6 `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` Azure Function application. I have install following libraries

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.20.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
```

I am trying to register `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()` but it is not been recognised, not sure what I missing here?

`Startup class`

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(abc.IS.ProcessingFunction.Startup))]
namespace abc.IS.ProcessingFunction
{
   public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
   {
     public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
     {
         builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
     }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72410098/932728

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to register service using

```
 builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
```