# Is it possible to use Js Interop with Mobile Blazor Bindings?

Tags: mobile, native, blazor

I try Mobile Blazor Bindings, following this tutorial :
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/mobile-blazor-bindings/walkthroughs/todo-app

I want to use HTML CSS and JS code to create a test app.

In razor page, try to inject @inject IJSInProcessRuntime jsRuntime but it make the app crash.

Is it possible to use Js Interop with Mobile Blazor Bindings ?

Comment: Just a suggestion if you want to use web standards to create a mobile app, then go with rock solid React Native. MBB is not production ready and it's all about do it in .NET

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. After some searching i find a way to do that.
It's still in development, so it's all on your own risk.
First, you need to [download](https://github.com/xamarin/MobileBlazorBindings) last version of master branch of MobileBlazorBindings (or clone repo to your local storage).
Then you need to do some [changes](https://github.com/soags/MobileBlazorBindings/commit/7abd02fe816869daee9f3915c2923c8b4199e18e) to source files.
After that you need to compile these projects and pack them to nuget package. [Link how to do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/contribute/build-from-source) (skip first step).
Then add these nuget packages and dll to your project from local storage. [There some helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-do-i-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally) (If package version is not 0.5.41 you can just rename files with that version, work for me).
And now you can use `@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime` and `JS.InvokeVoidAsync("function", params);`  in your razor component.

Find more [there](https://github.com/xamarin/MobileBlazorBindings/issues/150)