# Getting local Nuget Package into Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I have a nuget package file (*.nupkg) saved on my Desktop. I am trying to get this into my Visual Studio solution. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is it not available from a regular package manager? You'd usually just add a package reference. If you *only* have it as a file, you can create a new directory as a package manager source, and put the file in there.

Comment: @JonSkeet Would I still be able to reference it by doing that? And do you have a reference or steps on how to do this?

Comment: Yes, but you need to configure the local package source. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources

Comment: You can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10240180/779182

Comment: @Frank_FC that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps.

1. Open solution exploler of your project from Visual Studio.
2. Right click on the project in which you want add the nuget package.
3. Select Manage NuGet Packages.
4. Click on the settings icon present on the right top of the window.
5. Click on ' + ' and give a name add the nuget package location where it is saved in your local computer.
6. Click ok and switch "Package source" to your recently added one. which enables to search for the package from the newly added location.
7. Search and reference the package in your project.

Comment: I have tried this, and it does not seem to work.