# nuget with visual studio community

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am starting a new coding job with a new client.
The problem I am having is that a lot of issues with namespaces that can not be found or maybe missing directives or an assembly reference.  This, I think, is a common thing.  So I am wondering where I can download a free DLL from Microsoft that will do the trick and get me to compile my code.  The class the code is using that the compiler does not like is "GeoPoint".
A quick search online offered using nuget to install the package Azure.Core.
So, how do I do this?  I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019.  I am looking for some direction.  Please advise.

On my work computer, I went to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/ in my browser but it is blocked.  So, I am assuming now that I have to use visual studio itself to add new assemblies instead of using a browser.  Is that right or do I have to ask my administrator for access?

The page:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Core/
offers me another hint with "Package Manager"
I found under Project->Manage Nuget Packages..."   in visual studio but when i try to uplad a package I get an error message.

So, my manager said I fist need to download an assemply.

Please advise.

Comment: Please edit your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is simply regurgitation of information in the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey meaning to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem, and your current title is totally useless.

Comment: What is the error message "I get an error message"

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is how to Load a Nuget Package from Local Source, check this resource:
[How do I install a NuGet package .nupkg file locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-do-i-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally)

But, then again, why would you want to do that? Azure.Core is a publicly available Nuget, so it makes little sense to do it manually as you would lose out on easy upgrades from the package manager.

Here's a resource to help you install a Nuget Package from Public Sources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/consume?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows