# .net core nuget NLog.Web.AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I want to use NLog.Web.AspNetCore, but don't want to get it through nuget

The project directly refers to NLog.Web.AspNetCore.dll, using the UseNLog function, the compiler prompts that the component must be added 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0

But Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions is only version 2.2

what can i do

Comment: What version of .NET Core Platform is being used? .NET Core 2.1 / .NET Core 3.1 / .NET5 / .NET6 ?

Answer (score 0):

In the package I see it needs Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1+

[image]

See [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/5.1.1#dependencies-body-tab)

Answer (score 0):

you can download it to a path on your PC locally and install it manually,
for instance you can download it from https://nlog-project.org/ follow steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-do-i-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally) on how to install from a local path on your computer