# nuget.org: Unable to load the service index

Tags: nuget

This is not really a [Duplicate to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source) as the answers provided are not working and I am **using Windows-7 on a MacBook using Bootcamp**.

I am getting the following error while trying to search any package in the Nuget Package Manager:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       [nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
> An error occurred while sending the request.
> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

My NuGet Config File (`%appdata%/nuget`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you even reach that URL on your windows install?

Comment: @mxmissile Yes, I am able to access thw URL in  a browser

Comment: @skm I have the same issue, but I'm using VS on VirtualBox Win 7 VM. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @skm this answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/65424896/7991817

Answer (score 5):

Nuget.org started enforcing the use of TLS 1.2 (and dropped support for TLS 1.1 and 1.0). Check the DisabledByDefault value under,

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client in your registry.

To enable the support, please make sure you have an update installed and switch the support on:

`reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f /reg:32`

`reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f /reg:64`

`reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32`

`reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64`

Comment: This post saved my life

Comment: Updating VS fixed it for me

Comment: Mark it as the answer if it fixed your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Well.. let me try if this can save your day. I faced the same issue, and I tried everything mentioned in this post and few related posts (started 5-6 years ago) mentioned below, but unfortunately nothing worked.. until I had a **trick that solved my problem**. This could be a temp solution but could save hours if this glitch is caused by some Windows update or network policy or Anti Virus and what not!

**My situation:**
One of my few development PCs (Win11, Win10) with VS 2022 (17.7.5) started showing this error when building the solution from Visual Studio:

> [nuget] unable to load the service index for source
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.  an error occurred while sending
> the request. the remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org'

Interestingly the same was working on other PCs. I spent many hours debugging and following the below threads. Did many reboots, restarts.. nothing helped. Even I tried downloading VS 2019 to confirm and the same issue showed up.

```
C:\Windows\System32> ping api.nuget.org
Ping request could not find host api.nuget.org. Please check the name and try again.
```

So I realized this is a network thing that messed up on one of my PCs and it was not able to resolve the DNS for api.nuget.org. I'm coding for more than 2 decades but still the IP config and other networking stuff freaks me out!

**My Solution:**
I ran this on a good PC (command prompt):

```
C:\Windows\System32>ping api.nuget.org
Pinging part-0010.t-0009.t-msedge.net [13.107.246.38] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 13.107.246.38: bytes=32 time=71ms TTL=57
Reply from 13.107.246.38: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=57
...
```

and added this to the hosts file on the bad PC (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc):

```
13.107.246.38   api.nuget.org
```

...and boom!!!

Related posts (I tried all answers and it **didn't work** for me):

- [Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)
- [Visual Studio - Nuget - Unable to load the service index for source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773500/visual-studio-nuget-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)
- [NuGet Unable to load the service index for source Authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72229547/nuget-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source-authentication-failed)
- [NuGet Package Manager unable to load the service index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977703/nuget-package-manager-unable-to-load-the-service-index)

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me after trying about every other solution I found on the internet for hours.