# NuGet Unable to load the service index for source Authentication failed

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, tls1.2

Since today for some reason I'm unable to connect to the NuGet package manager through Visual Studio.

```
[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

But I cannot get it to work again...
Things I tried.

- Delete NuGet.config
- Clear NuGet cache
- Disable TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 explicitly
- Enabled TLS1.2 explicitly
- followed the manual from nuget at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/
- Different Visual Studios
- Update to the latest Visual Studio 2019
- Tried different TLS settings in the RegEdit for 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2. I don't have a TLS1.3 section yet.
- I can browse to https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with chrome

TLS1.2 Client settings:
[image: TLS1.2]

TLS1.2 Server settings:
[image: TLS1.2]

Specs:
Windows Server 2012R2, Visual Studio 2019

Also tried it on a different Windows Server 2012R2 machine and same problem

It is still working on my laptop with Windows 10.

Hopefully someone has an idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had exactly the same problem, running script from https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-tls12 and following instructions from it helped me.
In my case it generated additional script file, after running that and restaring pc nuget was working once again.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.

The solution was to install the [microsoft/artifacts-credprovider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider) as mentioned on that page.

```
Invoke-Expression "& { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.ps1) } -AddNetfx"
```

Comment: This solved my issues with restoring packages from an internal NuGet repository hosted on Azure from the CLI (which would fail even though VS22' restored without issue).

Answer (score 1):

one of the classic reason...

**Possible Problem: Stale Artifactory Credentials in Credential Manager**
You have saved credentials for your artifactory in credential manager. If your system/SSO credentials changed recently then this will happen.

**Solution: Update/Remove Saved credentials from Credentials Manager**
Go to Windows => Credentials manager => Windows Credentials => Generic Credentials => [Artifactory related Credentials] => Remove.

When you rebuild from visual studio it will again ask for fresh credentials. It's upto you whether want to save or add every time.

Credential manager - [[image: 1]]

Enter credentials after rebuild in VS [[image: 2]]