# Azure Pipeline Consuming Azure Artifact Nuget - NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/... (Q&A)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I am trying to have my Azure Pipeline get Nuget Packages from my Azure Artifacts feed, but they don't want to talk to each other.

I have followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#pipelines-permissions) and `'[Project name] Build Service ([Organization name])'` already seems to have rights, but I'm getting the following error.

> ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/.../.../nuget/v3/index.json.

My build is unchanged from before.

What should I do? (Q&A Below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, this seemed to be the fix:

1. Go to Artifacts > your artifact feed > 'Connect to feed' > Nuget.exe and copy the nuget config. Create a file called `nuget.config` at the same level as the sln (could be csproj level) and paste in the contents.
2. In Artifacts (Artifacts > Settings Cog > Permissions) You need `{project name} Build Service ({organization name})` AND `Project Collection Build Service ({organization name})` to have at least 'Collaborator' (you can have contributor) rights as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#pipelines-permissions).
3. In the build, two additional steps were required (might need to overwrite the existing nuget installer). I found this that referenced the [Nuget Authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69990652/852806), and I also needed to [install the Azure Artifacts Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74094508/852806). Start of the build shown below (was previously just the NugetToolInstaller step).

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

# Required for custom access to Artifacts
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Install Artifacts Provider"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Install Artifacts Provider"
      Invoke-Expression "& { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.ps1) } -AddNetfx"

# Check we can authenticate
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
  displayName: "Nuget Authentication"
```

Comment: Glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue. You could Accept it as an Answer , it could help other community members who get the same issues issue to find the solution easily.